# OS X : Terminal command to turn ON/OFF SSH server

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

I know how to turn on SSH server from System preferences :-

(System preferences ->  Sharing -> Remote Login )

Now I am looking for a terminal command for the same.

By knowing it I can use the command in my Python Script (for project work).

Comment: I am new to all this. I didn't know launchd and 'starting SSH from Terminal' are correlated. And there are thousands of generic questions like these which are asked in different ways.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can stop the ssh service by typing the following:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

To start it again, use this:

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```